# IOS development on windows pc

Tags: ios, flutter, windows

I've been creating Android apps as a hobby, but I've never released any. Now that I have an iPhone, I'd like to develop an app for personal use.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Flutter on my Windows machine to develop the app and then buy a second-hand MacBook solely for building it. Would my only expenses be the Apple Developer Program license and the MacBook?

Comment: Yes :) That would be all. You might even be able to run the app on your own phone without the Developer Program License. You won't be able to upload it to the AppStore though.

Comment: Sounds even better. since I probably won't be making something worth releasing just yet